# how to alter every auto increment field mysql

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I have an id column in my table which auto increments for every insert.

I need to put '00' in front of each auto increment number, so for example I insert the first record, the id field will be '1', I need this to be '001', then '002' for second etc.

Is this possible in mysql?

Comment: what type that column has?

Comment: why would you need to do that? If anything, just do it on display when you query out, but with a leading "00", that column is no longer a number but a string.

Comment: because i have 2 tables with matching id's its causing a problem

Comment: if its not possible ill have to change structure

Comment: if you have 2 tables that must match some columns - columns just need to be same type